Remove group of specific rows in panel data when multiple columns contain NA
I have a balanced panel data set df with columns:
id, time, var1, var2, var3, var4....

Some values in var1 and var4 contain Na elements.
If they contain the NA element, I want to remove all the corresponding id rows that contain the NA elements so that my data remains balanced.
So if var1 contains Na that corresponds to id=28, I want to remove all the id=28 rows.
Can I do that using Dplyr in R?
I did something like this:
df %>% select(c(var1,var4)) %>% group_by(id) %>% filter( !is.na(.))

But it doesn't work. Could you please provide some guidance?

Hi there, welcome to SO. Please take a moment and read the link at the end. You must always provide a sample or toy data, the problematic code, a description of what you're trying to do and the expected output. After the reading, please update your question https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example.

Always provide sample data to get better and faster answers.
Try filter with if_all and starts_with.
The code:
# Library(tidyverse)

set.seed(128)
aux <- tibble(
  id = 1:10, 
  time = now() + seconds(sample(c(rep(NA, 1000), -3600:3600), 10, replace = TRUE)) %>% hms::hms(),
  var1 = sample(c(NA, 1:10), 10, replace = TRUE),
  var2 = sample(c(NA, 1:10), 10, replace = TRUE),
  var3 = sample(c(NA, 1:10), 10, replace = TRUE),
  var4 = sample(c(NA, 1:10), 10, replace = TRUE))

aux <- filter(aux, if_all(starts_with("var"), \(x) !is.na(x)))

Input:
> aux
# A tibble: 10 × 6
      id time                 var1  var2  var3  var4
   <int> <dttm>              <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1     1 2024-04-11 16:30:32    NA    NA     3     1
 2     2 2024-04-11 16:11:08     3     5     1     9
 3     3 2024-04-11 14:47:42     5     2     9     4
 4     4 2024-04-11 15:43:26     7     6     6    NA
 5     5 NA                      6     2     5    10
 6     6 2024-04-11 15:18:34     5     3     4    NA
 7     7 2024-04-11 15:54:08     9    NA     7     8
 8     8 2024-04-11 16:19:12     1    10     7     9
 9     9 2024-04-11 15:46:24     2    NA     2    NA
10    10 2024-04-11 15:32:55     1     1     9     6

Output:
# A tibble: 5 × 6
     id time                 var1  var2  var3  var4
  <int> <dttm>              <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     2 2024-04-11 16:11:08     3     5     1     9
2     3 2024-04-11 14:47:42     5     2     9     4
3     5 NA                      6     2     5    10
4     8 2024-04-11 16:19:12     1    10     7     9
5    10 2024-04-11 15:32:55     1     1     9     6

